# Windows Forms ListView in Details Mode - How to Change Row Height in Owner Draw?

Tags: listview, winforms, ownerdrawn

I've got a Windows Forms ListView control in details mode. There are multiple columns at play. I'm trying to use owner draw to place a particularly wide column "below" the others.

So, instead of this:

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3  COLUMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN4
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3
COLUMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN4
```

I cannot figure out how to enlarge the bounds of the item to fit in the room to draw the column below. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rows in a ListView have to be the same height.  You can get a tall row that fits more than one line of text by making the Font large, then using a small font in the DrawItem event handler.

If this is too restrictive then you should look at DataGridView or a custom 3rd party component.

Answer (score 1):

A ListView cannot do such a thing. Well... it can, but only with [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) and even then it's not easy. There is a sample showing how to do something like that, but not quite:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/_images/task-list.png))</sub>

Try using Lee Paul Alexander’s fantastic [Outlook-style list](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/outlooklistcontrol.aspx).

[image]